# rostopic echo of a field of an array in ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, array, message, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have an issue trying to display a field of an array in a message in ROS Indigo with the command rostopic echo.
I'm trying to display the position of an object detected with the Ork package, using this command :

```
rostopic echo /recognized_object_array/objects[0]/pose/pose/pose/position
```

But I got this traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rostopic", line 35, in <module>
    rostopic.rostopicmain()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 1765, in rostopicmain
    _rostopic_cmd_echo(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 1136, in _rostopic_cmd_echo
    _rostopic_echo(topic, callback_echo, bag_file=options.bag)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 788, in _rostopic_echo
    index = submsg_class.__slots__.index(field)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__slots__'
```

But it works if I only do :

```
rostopic echo /recognized_object_array/objects[0]
```

This is just an example, I have the same issue with other custom messages using arrays.
Is there a specific syntax to display the field of an element of an array ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220434/rostopic-echo-of-a-field-of-an-array-in-ros-indigo/) by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should work in Indigo now (it didn't use to work in older Indigo releases, but now I tested it and it works).

The

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__slots__'
```

means you reference an invalid field in your topic path definition. Make sure you correctly type in all parts of the path and "dereference" all arrays.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-05-07**:
It works for me in Indigo:

```
rostopic echo /namespace/ball_tracking/ball_states/ball_states[0]/position
```

However if I would like to visualize that in rviz as pointstamped it does not work:
Error subscribing: Character [[] at element [49] is not valid in Graph...
Any ideas how to sole this?

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2018-05-07**:
Is your topic .../ball_states[0]/position of type PointStamped and is element 49 continuously published ? Just a guess, if you track a lot of balls, it's likely that your array has a different size each frame and so element 49 might not always exist. However I would suggest to open a new question.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-05-07**:
hm no the problem is that I am not allowed to used these brackets [ in rviz as topic name. And I do not know how to select the first element  of an array otherwise ..... :( thats the problem here.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2018-05-07**:
Ok I see, you could to write a simple node that does the translation to a MarkerArray of spheres which is resized dynamically and display your balls in rviz ?